# How to call react-native function from IOS native module(Plugins)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, barcode-scanner

I want to call react-native function from native module.

I have created one barcode-scanner plugins for my react-native app, barcode-scanner SDK is available in native IOS & Android so, i extract those native code and create one plugins(NPM) for react-native app.

Now my problems is, Once barcode-scanner scan a data and send to native IOS, how can i get those scanning data in my react-native app ?(I got scanned data in IOS native)

I want to call react-native app function once native module scanned a data and send those data in react-native

Please give example or proper document so i can try and implement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used "RCTDeviceEventEmitter" & "NativeEventEmitter" and add listener for received event

[more detail](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android#sending-events-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find your answer well described here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios#passing-properties-from-native-to-react-native

Comment: I already read those doc, i can't found proper example or solution.(I am beginner in react-native)

Comment: There is an example at this Page I posted above (sorry, in my previous answer I thought you wan't to do the opposite way). In the above Example look for `initialProperties:props`, this is the place to paste your props to pipe them to RN

Comment: I try to understand your updated link but not getting properly. if you have any demo or sample code  then share with me. I want to call react-native function from native IOS once Native IOS got a barcode scanner scanned a data.